# Implementing WebSQL into iOS 6+ / Android 4+ LOCAL-ONLY App

Tags: ios, cordova, web-sql

I am building an app that I want to be completely local on the device. I've been looking into ways to store the data on the device and it seems that WebSQL is persistent on iOS6+ devices.

I've been looking into the documentation on WebSQL and I'm a bit confused on how to add it to my project.

In the documentation they have

```
function prepareDatabase(ready, error) {
    return openDatabase('documents', '1.0', 'Offline document storage', 5*1024*1024, function (db){
        db.changeVersion('', '1.0', function (t) {
            t.executeSql('CREATE TABLE docids (id, name)');
        }, error);
    });
}

function showDocCount(db, span) {
    db.readTransaction(function (t) {
        t.executeSql('SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM docids', [], function (t, r) {
            span.textContent = r.rows[0].c;
        }, function (t, e) {
            // couldn't read database
            span.textContent = '(unknown: ' + e.message + ')';
        });
    });
}

prepareDatabase(function(db) {
    // got database
    var span = document.getElementById('doc-count');
    showDocCount(db, span);
}, function (e) {
    // error getting database
    alert(e.message);
});
```

They say that the 'prepareDatabase' function checks to see if the database already exists, but I don't see where that check is, unless the callback is **ONLY** called if the DB doesn't exist, which the API section seems to imply.

Also, what happens if the database size grows larger than the estimate provided at the time of creation?

Another question is just **HOW** persistent is the database? Will a user be shocked one morning when they open the app and see that all their data gone?

As always, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Opening websql database convoluted. The pattern is that you never specify version on `openDatabase`. But instead, let them open whatever and if version is not `1.0`, then you `changeVersion` to `1.0`.